# Select Count in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `[FeedbackPOS]` like this:

[image]

I want to get How many entry of 5/4/3/2/1 in [Q1],[Q2],[Q3]....[Q11]

Expected output:

```
Rating | Q1 | Q2 .... Q11
-------+----+-------------
5star  | 2  | 3
4star  | 0  | 0
3star  | 1  | 0
2star  | 0  | 0
1star  | 0  | 0 ..... Q11
```

Comment: How about `COUNT()` and `UNION`?

Comment: This number always random? It can be 5,4,3,2,1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is to unpivot the data and then re-pivot.  The following uses `apply` and conditional aggregation:

```
select v.stars,
       sum(case when v.q = 'q1' then 1 else 0 end) as q1,
       sum(case when v.q = 'q2' then 1 else 0 end) as q2,
       sum(case when v.q = 'q3' then 1 else 0 end) as q3,
       sum(case when v.q = 'q4' then 1 else 0 end) as q4,
       . . .
from t cross apply
     (values ('q1', q1), ('q2', q2), . . .
     ) v(q, stars)
group by v.stars
order by v.stars;
```

The need to unpivot the data suggests that you have a poor data model.  You should really have a table with a separate row per `q`.

EDIT:

Here is an alternative method if you want to start with all the ratings:

```
select v.stars,
       sum(case when t.q1 = v.stars then 1 else 0 end) as q1,
       sum(case when t.q2 = v.stars then 1 else 0 end) as q2,
       sum(case when t.q3 = v.stars then 1 else 0 end) as q3,
       . . .
from (values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5)) v(stars) cross join
     t
group by v.stars
order by v.stars;
```

Comment: `order by v.stars DESC;` cause the _Rating_ start with `5 Stars`

Comment: @gordonlinoff thankyou so much for ans its work perfectly but can u do one more favour  ? how to get 0 row when supose rating 1 is not available in table actually i want to create atleast 5 rows for 1 to 5 ratings

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like

```
CREATE TABLE T
(
  Q1 INT,
  Q2 INT,
  Q3 INT
  -- ...
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES
(5, 1, 2),
(5, 4, 5),
(3, 5, 5);

SELECT '5 Stars' Rating,
       (SELECT COUNT(Q1) FROM T WHERE Q1 = 5) Q1,
       (SELECT COUNT(Q2) FROM T WHERE Q2 = 5) Q2,
       (SELECT COUNT(Q3) FROM T WHERE Q3 = 5) Q3
UNION
SELECT '4 Stars' Rating,
       (SELECT COUNT(Q1) FROM T WHERE Q1 = 4) Q1,
       (SELECT COUNT(Q2) FROM T WHERE Q2 = 4) Q2,
       (SELECT COUNT(Q3) FROM T WHERE Q3 = 4) Q3
UNION
SELECT '3 Stars' Rating,
       (SELECT COUNT(Q1) FROM T WHERE Q1 = 3) Q1,
       (SELECT COUNT(Q2) FROM T WHERE Q2 = 3) Q2,
       (SELECT COUNT(Q3) FROM T WHERE Q3 = 3) Q3
UNION
SELECT '2 Stars' Rating,
       (SELECT COUNT(Q1) FROM T WHERE Q1 = 2) Q1,
       (SELECT COUNT(Q2) FROM T WHERE Q2 = 2) Q2,
       (SELECT COUNT(Q3) FROM T WHERE Q3 = 2) Q3
UNION
SELECT '1 Stars' Rating,
       (SELECT COUNT(Q1) FROM T WHERE Q1 = 1) Q1,
       (SELECT COUNT(Q2) FROM T WHERE Q2 = 1) Q2,
       (SELECT COUNT(Q3) FROM T WHERE Q3 = 1) Q3
```

Comment: I think it's not efficient when have so many column.. Like the op have..

Comment: @dwir182 It's another method beside to what Gordon provide :)

Comment: Great! :) @Sami